# Laravel Relationsship laod

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

```
        $jobs = EventJob::with(['applications' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('accepted', false);
        }, 'job' => function($query)   {
            $query->where('division_id', 1);
        }, 'event' => function($query) use ($date) {
            $query->where('date', '>=', $date);
        }])->get();
```

Complete overhaul of the question.

I wan't only the EventJob elements where the conditions in the $query are true but I get all the elements.

Comment: When you say you are stuck, what is the outcome you are getting versus the outcome you want?

Comment: I can get all Events after the specified date. But I have no clue how to get the EventJobs with the restriction of division_id on the Job Element that is referenced from the EventJob Element.

Comment: I will refactor the question.

Comment: Deleted previous comments as they are irrelevant. Having a look at new question now

Comment: **$events= Event::eventJobs()->where('date', '>=', $date)->get();** it will all **eventJobs** for specific **event** date .

Comment: @YasinPatel the date lies on the Event Model not the EventJob Model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the function you're looking for is `whereHas`, it is [documented here.](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations)

Your code would then be :

```
$jobs = EventJob::whereHas('applications', function ($query) {
    $query->where('accepted', false);
})->whereHas('job', function($query)   {
    $query->where('division_id', 1);
})->wherehas('event', function($query) use ($date) {
    $query->where('date', '>=', $date);
})->get();
```